# java.lang.ClassCastException: ListActivity cannot be cast to DatePickerDialog

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-listfragment, listactivity

I'm having problems to implement this [Material DatePicker](https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker) due to the `Context` call that I should probably be doing wrong.

The sample from GitHub works just fine because the Dialog is being created by an Activity.

However, at this particular case, I'm working with a `Fragment` attached to a `ListActivity`.

This is how I'm calling it:

```
Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
DatePickerDialog dpd = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(
(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity(),
now.get(Calendar.YEAR),
now.get(Calendar.MONTH),
now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)
);
dpd.show(getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
```

This line `(DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener) getActivity()` is generating the issue. It is declared as `MainActivity.this` in the sample, but I can't use `ListActivity.this` or something similar.

> Logcat
>
> Process: kva.ihm, PID: 16218
>       java.lang.ClassCastException: kva.ihm.ParameterListActivity cannot be cast to
>   com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.DatePickerDialog$OnDateSetListener
>               at kva.ihm.ParameterDetailFragment$49.onItemClick(ParameterDetailFragment.java:3839)

Comment: java's basic: given class is not implementing given interface

Comment: Yes i'm aware of it, but I'm not familiar with the correct call for this interface.

Comment: @AnirudhSharma it's not possible to make this call at all

Comment: *Yes i'm aware of it, but I'm not familiar with the correct call for this interface.* oh come one ... solution is simple: you should implement `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` in `ParameterListActivity` or pass there different instance of this interface implementation (which `ParameterListActivity` is not)

Comment: @Selvin this is already implemented a long way ago.

Comment: no, it is not ... you would not get this exception ... try to check your imports ... maybe you are implementing wrong interface (same name - different package)

Comment: Sir, *it was implemented*. I would never do that kind of mistake. Therefore, as you mentioned, it was wrongly associated by Android Studio auto imports. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Do not trust evil auto imports :) .... also do not call me "sir" :)

Comment: @Machado you call `getActivity()` in your code. So this code from fragment. What implement `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener`: activity or fragment?

Comment: @Machado Attach your ParameterListActivity  code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake.

As previously mentioned by *@Selvin* in the comments, the interface call was implemented, therefore, it was wrongly associated by Android Studio auto imports.

TIP: Do not trust evil auto imports. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your activity should implement `DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener` for handling callback `void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog dialog, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth);` from DatePicker.

Or you can handle it using anonim class:

```
DatePickerDialog dialog = DatePickerDialog.newInstance(new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    void onDateSet(DatePickerDialog dialog, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
        //Your code.
    }
}, year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
```